# Portable VFS library C++

Tags: c++, file-io, filesystems, portability

Has anyone ever come across a good file system virtualization library that meets these requirements?

- Cross platform: at least Win32 and Linux, preferably also OSX
- Support for protocols:

  - SMB
  - FTP
  - SFTP
  - Local FS
- Abstract C++ interface with a client factory based on a URL:

  - smb://[user[:password]@]host/share/path...
  - ftp://[user[:password]@]host/path...
  - sftp://[user[:password]@]host/path...
  - file://path...
- Provide methods for:

  - Listing a directory, preferably returning entries with struct stat-like attributes
  - Move
  - Copy
  - Remove
  - Stat
  - Bonus: low level file access interface (open, read, write, close, ...)

I've seen some good libraries that meet a subset of these requirements (curl for FTP, libssh for SFTP, to name a few), but none yet that does it all.
There is a strong urge coming for a DIY, but I cannot imagine that it doesn't exist already.

Comment: You're asking for a lot... esp. when it comes to the cross-platform stuff.

Answer (score 3):

It's implemented in C, not C++, but I'm pretty sure [GIO](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/) supports most of that. This is the part of the GNOME project and is used by most GNOME applications as a file system abstraction.

Comment: Thanks Celada. Do you think GIO would be fully functional on Windows, especially the gvfs part?

Comment: I have my doubts as to whether they managed to implement the part where the virtual filesystem is mounted in the real filesystem but I figure you should at least be able to fully use the native GIO high-level interface (wherein files are identified by URLs). But I cannot be sure, I haven't used it in Windows. One way or the other, whatever the glib folks *have* managed to do, I doubt anyone else has done better.